# Electron, Creating Duplicate of Main Window On Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, electron

I am making an **electron** app and the user to be able to open as many instances of the main window (the one that opens by default) as they would like.

I would like them to be able to do this by simply clicking a button within the `index.html`.

How would this be possible within the following default apps code ?

`main.js`

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <!-- https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#csp-meta-tag -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="openWindow()">click to open new window</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is send a message to your main process when you click your button, then in `main.js` create a new window whenever we receive that message.

So first send a message to `main.js` from your `openWindow()` function like this:

```
var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
function openWindow () {
    ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'createNewWindow');
}
```

Then we listen for the message in `main.js` like this:

```
var ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', function (evt, message) {
    if (message == 'createNewWindow') {
        // Message received.
        // Create new window here.
    }
});
```

Then all you need to do is create a new window when you receive the `'createNewWindow'` message.

[See docs for sending a message to the main process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-args)

[See docs for receiving messages in the main process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#ipcmainonchannel-listener)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, how exactly do we create a new window

Comment: @AlexHawking You would create the window the same way you create your main window already, essentially just call `createWindow()` again.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal in two ways.

You should change your `index.html` to like this as pre-requirements
At your `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <body>
    <button onclick="require('./renderer.js').openWindow()">click to open new window</button>
  </body>
    <!-- All of the Node.js APIs are available in this renderer process. -->
    We are using Node.js <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chromium <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.

    <script>
      // You can also require other files to run in this process
      require('./renderer.js')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> 1. Using ipc Communiation.

At your `main.js`

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
let browserWindows = [];

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  let newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  newWindow.loadFile('index.html')


  newWindow.on('closed', function () {
    newWindow = null
  })

  browserWindows.push(newWindow)
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

ipcMain.on('createNewWindow', (evnet, args) => {
  createWindow();
})
```

At your `renderer.js`

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
module.exports.openWindow = event => {
  ipcRenderer.send('createNewWindow', {});
}
```

> 2. Not using ipc.
>      you can create directly. Create `browserWindow` directly at your renderer without ipc
>      Communitaion. Hence you enable the node api at your renderer. So that

At your `renderer.js`

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote
module.exports.openWindow = event => {
  const newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
      }
    })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  newWindow.loadFile('index.html')
}
```

In this way, you don't need to change your `main.js`

Comment: An important note on Solution #2: although it doesn't actually use the `ipcMain` module, the `remote` module still uses inter-process communication behind the scenes and can cause race conditions.

For that reason and others, it can be a headache for apps and will be deprecated in the next major version of Electron (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21408) and the associated blog post).

Comment: Good, comment. @Erik. But for just creating the duplicate window, I don't think this won't occur the big performance issue. ;)

Comment: Plus I'd say, for the best performance, all the backend operation sth like (file operation, process handling, DB mange, etc) should be handled at the `main` process.